# Struts2 get the text boxes (dynamic) to action class

Tags: class, jsp, struts2, action

I have struts page where the text boxes are with dynamic ID and wanted to get this values into Action class. Can someone please help me with the code plz.

Answer (score 0):

Why did no one answer this question? Its a bit late to answer this question though. Well append all the data of textboxes in some format like json. Your URL will look something like  `/someclass.action?knownvariable=[{textbox1:value1},{textbox2:value2}]` and pass it as one variable whose name is fixed. In Action class these data can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Silpa, probably remove that parameter as below and use getter setter methods. Hope this helps.

```
public String retrieveDataFromDB() {
   // Do something here 
   return "SUCCESS";
}

public void setKnownvariable(String knownvariable){
    this.knownvariable=knownvariable;
}

public String getKnownvariable(){
     return knownvariable;
}

private String knownvariable;
```